# Java and C# - byte array to long conversion difference

Tags: c#, java, numbers, arrays

This is strange to me: 
when I run in Java

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 50, -106, 40, -22, -94, -119, -52, 8 };
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap( data );
System.out.println( bb.getLong() );
```

result is 3645145936617393160

when I run in C#

```
//unsigned values (signed&0xff)
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 50, 150, 40, 234, 162, 137, 204, 8 };
long l = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
System.Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\n", l));
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

result is 634032980358633010

Can you help me to understand this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a difference in [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

If you reverse the byte array, it works as expected:

```
BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] { 8, 204, 137, 162, 234, 40, 150, 50 }, 0)
```

You can set the endianness in Java by calling [`bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29).

By the way, the easiest way to play with these things is to use [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net).

Comment: Specifically, Java stores things internally as Big Endian, while x86 processors are Little Endian... and presumably .NET's design reflects this.