# Issue sending an array of bytes representing an integer from c# to java client

Tags: c#, java, int, arrays, converters

I am trying to send an array of byte representing an integer from a c# ASP.Net page to a java client as follows

```
public void WriteToStream(int i)
{
    byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    var writer = new MemoryStream();
    // Little - Endians to Big - Endians;
    Array.Reverse(buffer);
    // Unsigned Char to Signed Char
    sbyte[] suffer = (sbyte[])(Array)buffer;
    BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(writer);
    foreach (var sb in suffer)
    {
        binaryWriter.Write(sb);
    }
    binaryWriter.Close();
    buffer = writer.ToArray();
    writer.Close();
    // Writing to an Aspx Page Response Output Stream
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

and on java side

```
public int getInt(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    ByteArrayInputStream reader = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    buffer = new byte[4];
    reader.read(buffer, 0, 4);
    int i = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getInt();
    return i;
}
```

These procedures work correctly for integers less than **128** but for **128** the java side returns **239**. I know that the issue is related to the fact that java memory storage is **Big – Endians Signed Bytes** while .Net C# is **Little – Endians Unsigned Bytes**. I’m also aware of the following posts

[Get int from bytes in Java, encoded first in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159713/get-int-from-bytes-in-java-encoded-first-in-c-sharp)

[different results when converting int to byte array - .NET vs Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918133/different-results-when-converting-int-to-byte-array-net-vs-java)

[Java and C# - byte array to long conversion difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289427/java-and-c-sharp-byte-array-to-long-conversion-difference?rq=1)

however I cannot change the java side as the above posts suggest. I have to modify C# side to suit other end.

How may I do that?

**[UPDATED]**

I changed the C# side based on [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) as follows

```
public void WriteToStream(int i)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new EndianBinaryWriter(EndianBitConverter.Big, stream);
    writer.Write(i);
    byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();
    // Writing to an Aspx Page Response Output Stream
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

however the result has not changed. Java still returns **239** (while expecting **128**)

Why? and how may I correct it?

Comment: 128 going to 239 suggest something other than endianess is causing a problem. I suggest you output the byte stream in hex formatted bytes and make sure that the data going into the connection is correct and matches the data coming out of the connection before converting the bytes into ints.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Use Jon Skeet's EndianBinaryWriter, available as part of [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question to reflect your suggestion however the problem is still there. Would you please have look at that to see where I may make mistake? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that the number between -128 and 127 work fine but anything higher that 128 does not work is because one of the sides is handling the bytes as signed.

For this I suggest that on your **C#** side you use the **getbuffer** method that returns unsigned bytes

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx**

And also for the JAVA side you can take a look at the USIGNED LINK that is mentioned on this answer

**[Converting raw-byte values into Java types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708141/converting-raw-byte-values-into-java-types)**